# Two-thirds of screen is green when encode with MediaCodec

Tags: android, ios, video, android-mediacodec

I am working on a project that needs to process a video using OpenGL on Android. I decided to use MediaCodec and I managed to get it works with the help from [ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java). The result is quite good, I have it receives a video, extracts the tracks, decodes the videotrack, edits with OpenGL, and encodes to a video file.

The problem is that the result video can be play well on Android, but when it comes to iOS, two-thirds of the screen is green.

I tried to solve with the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405018/android-video-decoder-not-drawing-to-gles-surface-on-lollipop-only), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215636/re-encoding-h-264-content-with-a-different-bit-rate-using-android-mediacodec), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356314/received-wrong-frame-data-with-extractmpegframestest-in-android), experiment different formats for the encoder, but the problem is still the same.

Could someone suggest me the reasons that can cause this problem and how to fix it?

[This is the video when it's played on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe7RZ.png)

This is the configuration for the encoder

```
MediaCodec mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 540, 960);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 2000000);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
```

**Update**
I wonder if i had any mistake with the video orientation, because the working partial of the output video has the same ratio as the desired output resolution, but in horizontal orientation. The input is vertical recorded, so does the desired output.
Here is the code of the decoder configuration:

```
inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH, 540);
inputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT, 960);
inputFormat.setInteger("rotation-degrees", 90);

String mime = inputFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
MediaCodec decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
decoder.configure(inputFormat, surface, null, 0);
```

**Update Dec 25:** I've tried different resolutions and orientations when configuring both encoder and decoder to check if the video's orientation is the problem or not, but the output video just got rotated, the green problem is still there.
I also tried "video/mp4v-es" for the encoder, the result video is viewable on Mac, but the iPhone cannot even play it.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong, but you can find a working example of GLES-filtered video in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika, demo at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg ). Are you using MediaMuxer to save it as a .mp4, or trying to play the raw H.264 stream on iOS?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i'll take a look at Grafika.
Right now i'm using MediaMuxer to save the file as .mp4. It can be played on any device, but except my android, the issue is still the same on others.

Comment: I wonder if i had any mistake with the video orientation, because the working partial of the output video has the same ratio as the desired output resolution, but in horizontal orientation.

Comment: **Update Dec 25:** I've tried different resolutions and orientations when configuring both encoder and decoder to check if the video's orientation is the problem or not, but the output video just got rotated, the green problem is still there.
I also tried "video/mp4v-es" for the encoder, the result video is viewable on Mac, but the iPhone cannot even play it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just solved it. The reason turns out to be the MediaMuxer, it wraps the h264 raw stream in some sort of container that iOS cant understand. So instead of using MediaMuxer, I write the raw h264 stream from the encoder to a file, and use [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) to mux it into a mp4 file.

Comment: @HuyDuongTu: My config is based on the [ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java). Everything is nearly the same, but instead of using the outputs of the audio and video encoders to feed the MediaMuxer, I used them to output into two separated files, one for audio and one for video, then mux them into one final file using mp4parser

Comment: @HuyDuongTu: but be careful with the audio stream, the original output of the audio encoder can't be used for muxing later, you should modify it a little bit using [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862715/how-to-generate-the-aac-adts-elementary-stream-with-android-mediacodec/18970406#18970406) before write it to the output file

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer now: It has to do with the fps range. I changed the fps rate on my camera params and on the media codec and suddenly it worked!